# rsyslog for beginners

Tags: rsyslog

I've just started to use rsyslog on an ubuntu 14 server. I am using it as a server to send logs from my firewalls / nas / routers etc.

New to all this so could do with some advice. Firstly, how to properly setup rsyslog to run as a server? I have it working, receiving information from the other devices but is there a better way to set this up other than the default. What about storing it in a mysql database?

Secondly, I am looking for a web interface to manage it all. Preferably something clean, easy to use and realtime(if thats possible) I have had a look at logzilla which looks perfect but is no longer free. So what would people recommend?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have rsyslog running then it is, essentially, "properly setup".  Customization is going to be based on your specific needs.  If you can provide more detail we can probably give better advice.

As far as analyzing the data, LOGalyzer is open source.  You can check it out here:

http://logalyze.com

It takes a bit of work to get running properly, but it's free.  You can also pay for support, but their prices are relatively hefty, especially if this is for non-work purposes.